# Having trouble checking for null condition in coffee script

Tags: function, null, coffeescript, arguments

I have a coffee script with the following

```
@update_states = (countryElt, stateElt, callbackFn) ->
    …
       if callbackFn != null
         callbackFn()
```

The problem is, even when there is no “callbackFn” argument passed to the function, the “if” block is getting executed.  What is the proper way to check if the argument is not null (i.e. is a function passed to the function)?

Comment: Almost certainly an indentation error. Try placing it on one line `if cb then cb()`, or for a more robust version `if typeof cb is 'function' then cb()` and see if that fixes. Also, have you looked at the output JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know but taht did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code `if callbackFn != null` is converted to `if(callbackFn !== null)`. If You don't pass the `callbackFn` argument, `callbackFn = undefined`. `undefined !== null`.

Correct way to do this in coffeescript is:

```
if callbackFn? then callbackFn()
```

Read more about [existential operators](http://coffeescript.org/#existential-operator)